# Any two permutations of type 2+2+1 are conjugate in A5

Tags: abstract-algebra

Proposition: Any two permutations of type 2+2+1 are conjugate in A5

In S5 two permutations are conjugate iff they have same cycle type. However it is not true for alternating group i think. I am stuck about proving theorem. ıs there any way to prove the theorem?

Answer (score 0):

The number of $2+2+1$ cycles in $A_5$ is five times (for the $1$-cycle) the $3$ $2+2$ cycles in $A_4$ giving $15$ 2+2+1 cycles in $A_5$. On the other hand the centralizer of an element $(ab)(cd)$ is the Klein Vierer Gruppe generated by $(ab)(cd)$ and $(ac)(bd)$ with four elements giving an orbit (conjugacy class) also of size $15$.